# How do I access nested SQL tables in R?

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, r-dbi, dbplyr

From R Studio's [ODBC database documentation](https://db.rstudio.com/odbc/) I can see a simple example of how to read a SQL table into an R data frame:

```
data <- dbReadTable(con, "flights")
```

Let me paste a graphic of the `BGBUref` table(?) I'm trying to read to an R data frame. This is from my connection pane in R studio.

[image: nested table]

If I use the same syntax as above, where `con` is the output of my `dbConnect(...)`  I get the following:

```
df <- dbReadTable(con, "BGBURef")
#> Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM "BGBURef"' nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: 
#> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name
#> 'BGBURef'.
```

Is my understanding of what a "table" is incorrect? Or do I need to do something like this to get to the nested `BGBUref` table:

```
df <- dbReadTable(con, "QnRStore\dbo\BGBURef")
#> Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""QnRStore\d"
```

The `BGBUref` data frame will come up in R Studio if I click on the little spreadsheet icon. I just can't figure out how to get it into a defined data frame, in my case `df`.

---

Here's the output when I run these commands:

```
df <- dbReadTable(con, "QnRStore")
#> Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM "QnRStore"'
#> nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL 
#> Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'QnRStore'.
```

and:

```
dbListTables(con)
#>  [1] "spt_fallback_db"                                         
#>  [2] "spt_fallback_dev"                                        
#>  [3] "spt_fallback_usg"                                        
#>  [4] "spt_monitor"                                             
#>  [5] "trace_xe_action_map"                                     
#>  [6] "trace_xe_event_map"                                      
#>  [7] "spt_values"                                              
#>  [8] "CHECK_CONSTRAINTS"                                       
#>  [9] "COLUMN_DOMAIN_USAGE"                                     
#> [10] "COLUMN_PRIVILEGES" 
#> ...
#> [650] "xml_schema_types"                                        
#> [651] "xml_schema_wildcard_namespaces"                          
#> [652] "xml_schema_wildcards"
```

Comment: `QnRStore` should be the output of the `dbConnect` function.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft Thanks for that first tip. I just updated the question to reflect these changes. Any additional input?

Comment: That's not a "nested" table.  It's a table named 'BGBUref" in the default schema 'dbo' of a database called QnRStore.  The error you posted still says ` object 'QnRStore' not found`.  Is that correct?

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft Sorry, I didn't have the errors updated in my edited post. Now the error messages are correct (mirror what I actually get). Hope that helps.

Comment: What does dbListTables output?

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft Added the output of `dbListTables(con)` to my question. Also dumped the entire output into a text editor, searched for both `BGBURef` and `QnRStore` and they're not there. But I can click on that spreadsheet icon and `BGBURef` comes up in R Studio!

Comment: Then your dbConnect is connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft I changed the `Database` argument to `Database = QnRStore` and now everything works properly. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**General Background**

Before anything, consider reading on the relational database architecture where tables are encapsulated in schemas which themselves are encapsulated in databases which are then encapsulated in servers or clusters. Notice the icons in your image correspond to the object type:

```
cluster/server < catalog/database < schema/namespace < table
```

Hence, there is no nested tables in your situation but a typical architecture:

```
myserver < QnRStore < dbo < BGBURef
```

To access this architecture from server-level in an SQL query, you would use period-qualifying names:

```sql
SELECT * FROM database.schema.table

SELECT * FROM QnRStore.dbo.BGBURef
```

The default schema for SQL Server is `dbo` (by comparison for Postgres it is `public`). Usually, DB-APIs like R's `odbc` connects to a database which allows connection to any underlying schemas and corresponding tables, assuming the connected user has access to such schemas. Please note this rule is not generalizable. For example, Oracle's schema aligns to owner and MySQL's database is synonymous to schema.

See further reading:

- [What is the difference between a schema and a table and a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298739/what-is-the-difference-between-a-schema-and-a-table-and-a-database/23025511)
- [Differences between Database and Schema using different databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869522/differences-between-database-and-schema-using-different-databases)
- [Difference between database and schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323740/difference-between-database-and-schema)
- [What's the difference between a catalog and a schema in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022755/whats-the-difference-between-a-catalog-and-a-schema-in-a-relational-database)
- [A database schema vs a database tablespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120219/a-database-schema-vs-a-database-tablespace)

---

**Specific Case**

Therefore, to connect to an SQL Server database table in a default schema, simply reference the table, `BGBURef`, which assumes the table resides in the `dbo` schema of your connecting database.

```
df <- dbReadTable(con, "BGBURef")
```

If you use a non-default schema, you will need to specify it accordingly which recently you can do with `DBI::Id` and can use it similarly for `dbReadTable` and `dbWriteTable`:

```
s <- Id(schema = "myschema", table = "mytable")

df <- dbReadTable(con, s)

dbWriteTable(conn, s, mydataframe)
```

Alternatively, you can run the needed period qualifying SQL query:

```
df <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM [myschema].[mytable]")
```

And you can use [`SQL()`](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/schema/#write-non-temporary-tables) for writing to persistent tables:

```
dbWriteTable(con, SQL("myschema.mytable"), mydataframe)
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `dbplyr` it appears that

```
df = tbl(con, from = 'BGBUref')
```

if roughly equivalent to

```
USE QnRStore
GO

SELECT * FROM BGBUref;
```

From @David_Browne's comment and the image it looks like you have:

- A table named 'BGBUref'
- In a schema named 'dbo'
- In a database called 'QnRStore'

In this case you need the `in_schema` command.

If your connection (`con`) is to the `QnRStore` database then try this:

```
df = tbl(con, from = in_schema('dbo', 'BGBUref'))
```

If your connection (`con`) is not to the `QnRStore` database directly then this may work:

```
df = tbl(con, from = in_schema('QnRStore.dbo', 'BGBUref'))
```

(I use this form when accessing multiple databases via the same connection. Because `dbplyr` performs best if you use the same connection when joining between tables from different databases.)