# Connect to Database Using dbPool RJDBC in R

Tags: r, rjdbc

I am trying to use a `pool` to connect to my database in R, but I get the error:

```
Schema must be specified when session schema is not set
```

How does one specify a schema ? It seems like I need to specify it inside the pool. If that's the case, what's the parameter name for a schema?

```
pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RJDBC::JDBC(
    "xxx",
    "dir_to_jar", "`"
  ),
  dbname = "db",
  schema = "schema" # this didn't work
  url = url,
  user = user,
  password = password,
  SSL = 'true'
)

pool %>% tbl("schema.table")
```

Comment: `dbplyr::in_schema`?

Comment: I think this'll work if I know how to add a catalog name. Do you know how to add a catalog to ```in_schema```?

Comment: This may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58289494/3358272.

Comment: Unless you are able to do this with `DBI`/`RJDBC` (no pool), then I suggest this warrants the [tag:dbi] (and/or [tag:r-dbi]) tag. If this behavior persists with `DBI::dbConnect`, then I think it might be preferred to test with that vice confusing things with connection-pools. If you have the ability to do this with the `odbc` package (instead of `RJDBC`), then that tag is not needed ... but I'm guessing you're using `RJDBC` because of your specific DBMS. What is the DBMS?

Comment: I am using Starburst. I'm not sure if this is a DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

I tried several other methods using `DBI::dbConnect` combined with `Id` and it worked:

```
pool <- DBI::dbConnect(
  drv = RJDBC::JDBC(
    "xxx",
    "dir_to_jar", "`"
  ),
  url = url,
  user = user,
  password = password,
  SSL = 'true'
)

# Didn't work
pool %>% tbl(dbplyr::in_schema("catalog.schema", "table"))

# Works!
s <- Id(catalog = "catalog", schema = "schema", table = "table")
df <- dbReadTable(pool, s)
```